# Dynamic Order by and sort by column

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have to show data in a UI grid and pick the data from coming from two different tables in SQL Server 2014.

Data can be sort by any column coming from UI code and can be sort by both direction (ASC/DESC). Direction also being passed by UI code.

In my current implementation we are using CTE as below  -

```
    ;WITH cte AS
    (SELECT ED.JobExecutionID
        , ED.RowNumber
        , ED.ErrorMessage
        , ED.RowData    
        , CASE 
            WHEN @SortKey = 'RowNumber' AND @SortDirection = 'Ascending' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.RowNumber ASC)
            WHEN @SortKey = 'RowNumber' AND @SortDirection = 'Descending' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.RowNumber DESC)
            WHEN @SortKey = 'ErrorMessage' AND @SortDirection = 'Ascending' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.ErrorMessage ASC)
            WHEN @SortKey = 'ErrorMessage' AND @SortDirection = 'Descending' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.ErrorMessage DESC)
            WHEN @SortKey = 'RowData' AND @SortDirection = 'Ascending' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.RowData ASC)
            WHEN @SortKey = 'RowData' AND @SortDirection = 'Descending' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.RowData DESC)
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  ED.RowNumber ASC)
         END AS SortRowNumber       
    FROM ExceptionDetails ED        
    JOIN ExecutionDetails IED ON IED.JobExecutionID = ED.JobExecutionID
    WHERE ED.JobExecutionID = @JobExecutionId
),
RESULTS AS  
    (SELECT * FROM cte) 
SELECT JobExecutionID
    , RowNumber
    , ErrorMessage
    , RowData
    , SortRowNumber
FROM RESULTS
WHERE SortRowNumber BETWEEN @StartRowNumber AND @EndRrowNumber
ORDER BY SortRowNumber
```

I would like to get rid of CTE any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the CTE?

Comment: Do we not have any better option ? particularly I think I can pass column name dynamically also but not able to pass direction dynamically.

Comment: This marked as duplicated with reference, but I think there are better solutions using sp_executesql

Answer (score 0):

You can just move the case expression into an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT    ED.JobExecutionID
        , ED.RowNumber
        , ED.ErrorMessage
        , ED.RowData    
FROM ExceptionDetails ED        
JOIN ExecutionDetails IED ON IED.JobExecutionID = ED.JobExecutionID
WHERE ED.JobExecutionID = @JobExecutionId
ORDER BY CASE 
         WHEN @SortKey = 'RowNumber' AND @SortDirection = 'Ascending' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.RowNumber ASC)
         WHEN @SortKey = 'RowNumber' AND @SortDirection = 'Descending' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.RowNumber DESC)
         WHEN @SortKey = 'ErrorMessage' AND @SortDirection = 'Ascending' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.ErrorMessage ASC)
         WHEN @SortKey = 'ErrorMessage' AND @SortDirection = 'Descending' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.ErrorMessage DESC)
         WHEN @SortKey = 'RowData' AND @SortDirection = 'Ascending' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.RowData ASC)
         WHEN @SortKey = 'RowData' AND @SortDirection = 'Descending' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.RowData DESC)
         ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ED.RowNumber ASC)
         END
```

Comment: Yeah, but OP is also constraining by that calc:`WHERE SortRowNumber BETWEEN @StartRowNumber AND @EndRrowNumber`. I guess you could add the case statement again in the where clause, but a derived table or a CTE, or a stored procedure, would be cleaner.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah I completely overlooked that, good eye.  I agree with the CTE approach as well.  I really only answered to show that `CASE` and `ROW_NUMBER` can be used directly in the `ORDER BY`.  Could use `OFFSET @StartRowNumber ROWS FETCH NEXT @EndRowNumber-@StartRowNumber ROWS ONLY` with this method, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I can use order by clause like that -  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @SortKey)  AS SortRowNumber and it takes @SortKey dynamically and worked fine but somehow I am not able to pass ASC/DESC the same way.

Comment: @Gaurav You'll have to add the full thing like above, where the direction is hardcoded based on each case outcome.